# Apache Tomcat server not displaying HTML created in doGet() method in Intellij Idea 14 Ultimate

Tags: java, macos, apache, tomcat, intellij-idea

first off I'm running this off of Mac OSx. I have downloaded the latest binary version of Apache Tomcat, and linked it within my setting in intellij. It runs but it displays a blank page within Safari.. Here is the code in my doGet method:

```
protected void doGet(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
    pw.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
    pw.println("<html>");
    pw.println("<head lang=en>");
    pw.println("<meta charset= UTF-8>");
    pw.println("<script src= https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js></script>");
    pw.println("<script src = javascript.js></script>");
    pw.println("<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href=style.css>");
    pw.println("<title>Info</title>");
    pw.println("</head>");
    pw.println("<body><h1>HELLO</h1></body>");
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
}
```

The file structure for my lab is as follows:

```
- Lab 5
    -.idea
    -lib
    -out
    -src
        -InfoServlet.java
    -web
        -WEB-INF
        -index.jsp
        -style.css
```

Another thing I should note is that the URL that is opened by default is:

```
http://localhost:8080
```

It's acceptable that it's 8080 because I set the port to that. Could it be that my servlet isn't opening to the right URL page?

I really appreciate any help!

Comment: where is you web.xml file?

Comment: @ScaryWombat within WEB-INF mate.

Answer (score 0):

You should give servlet's artifact (url to your servlet) in @WebServlet annotation.Artifact is added in urlPatterns attribute. You also can specify multiple paths to your servlet. Don't forget that urlPatterns is array-like attribute. Example:

```
@WebServlet(name = "TestServlet", urlPatterns = {"/test","/servlets/test"})
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Test</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>This is a test designed to provoke an emotioanl response...Shall we continue?</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

Also make sure you configured your tomcat server correctly and its artifact. I had same problem with my tomcat 8 server.[This link](https://federicoponte.wordpress.com/2013/08/02/setting-up-tomcat-7-with-intellij-idea/) helped me.